# Improving performance of nested dropdownlist in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, performance, list, nested, drop-down-menu

I have a series of nested dropdown lists, each time when I select an item from the dropdown list it consumes a lot of time as I am binding other dropdowns based on the selection in pageLoad.

Is there any way I can improve the performance?

Comment: You need to show some more information to enable anybody to help. There are a thousand ways to implement the functionality you mention. How do you expect anybody to help without code samples and timings etc!

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it's hard to formulate an exact answer, but in general terms, you could implement page methods and ajax.  That would do the trick.